# Populate an auto increment type ID on an existing MySQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an existing MySQL Database that is accessed with PHP.  There is about 15,000 records and I need to quickly go in and update a new `Design Number` column that was just added.  I need to iterate the whole dataset and set the value for the first record as 00001, the next 00002, and keep incrementing by one until I get to the end.  I have code in place to make sure all new records will have this applied but I need to update the existing 15,000 records quickly.

Is there a quick way to do this in MySQL without building a PHP script to quickly populate all the old records?

Keep in mind this is not a regular auto increment filed in MySQL but instead a custom implementation to mimic that functionality in SugarCRM

I need to iterate this table...

```
SELECT designnumber_c FROM d1_designs_cstm
```

Then update this `designnumber_c` column and increment by +1 for each record while also maintaining a `00001` `0` padding

Comment: for that quick: unset primary key, create this new field and set it as primary - autonumber, save the table. It will write data for that field from 1 to 15000, then go back and unset new primary key and set the original one to make it as original.

Comment: If you add an autoinc to an existing table doesn't it populate itself?

Comment: @Popnoodles: yes, that's the point I thought but my suggestion wouldn't work anyway since it looks to be not a numeric field.

Comment: @jasondavis: is designnumber_c a text field?

Comment: @smozgur It could be changed to a string to pad zeros after creation, but it makes more sense to keep a numeric autoinc and pad zeros in any SELECT statement.

Comment: @Popnoodles: Good point. The exact solution is below by the way (Patrick's answer), with only 6 to 5 change but I thought this might be a quick dirty solution that could be even applied in phpmyadmin. Anwyay, let me vote on the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
mysql> SET @id := 0;
mysql> UPDATE d1_designs_cstm SET designnumber_c = LPAD(@id:=@id+1, 6, '0');
```

Comment: This seems very cool and like it is what I need but strangly when I run this, I then browse my records and see it counting 1-30 for my first set, I then reload the page and they are all set to null again...it's really odd like it's not saving

Comment: Did you actually check the column value in the database? regards, Patrick

Answer (score 2):

To add more on [*Answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22431736/767881) by [*@Patrick Savalle*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1199612/patrick-savalle)

You can have the new column definition as

```
designnumber_c int(6) unsigned zerofill not null
```

with this:

1. You need not explicitly pad zeros to it.
2. You can select, update, delete the column by actual value than by
   zero padded value.

**Example**:

```
mysql> SET @id := 0;
mysql> UPDATE d1_designs_cstm 
    ->   SET designnumber_c = @id:=@id+1;
```